# Modifying Sign Up tab created using django framework

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-models

I have made a sign up tab that registers new users and log in page that allows the registered users to continue with the site. I want if any registered user (having a registered email) tries to sign up again , an error message should pop up saying 'You are already having an account. Please Log in'.
I stored the data(s) of registered user(s) in a table created in models.py named SignedUpUsers.
Please help me achieve my task.

**models.py**

```
# Create your models here.


class SignedUpUsers(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=122)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
from Home.models import SignedUpUsers
from django.contrib import messages
from datetime import datetime

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        cont = SignedUpUsers(name=name,email=email,username=username,password=password,date=datetime.today())
        cont.save()
        messages.success(request,"\t\tYour account has successfully been created . Kindly Log In\t\t")
    return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

**signup.html**

```
<!--Form-->
<form method="post" action="/signup" style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 260px;
    left: 500px;
    font-size: larger;
">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <!--Email-->
  <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" size="25" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@example.com" style="block-size: 25px; position: absolute; left: 120px;">
  </div>
    <!--Name-->
    <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="name" style="position: absolute;left: 0px;top: 30px;">Name</label>
    <input type="text" size="25" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Arbaaz Ahmed" style="block-size: 25px;position: absolute;left: 120px;top: 30px;">
  </div>
    <!--Username-->
    <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="username" style="position: absolute;left: 0px;top: 60px;">Username</label>
    <input type="text" size="25" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="arbaazahmed2134" style="block-size: 25px;position: absolute;left: 120px;top: 60px;">
  </div>
    <!--Password-->
    <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="password" style="position: absolute;left: 0px;top: 90px;">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" size="25" id="password" name="password" style="block-size: 25px;position: absolute;left: 120px;top: 90px;">
  </div>
    <!--Sign up Button-->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 120px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    height: 27px;
    width: 100px
">Sign Up</button>
</form>

<!--Account Created-->
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages%}
<div class="alert alert-{{message.tags}}" role="alert" style="position: absolute; background-color: aqua; left: 470px; top: 430px">
  <!--<h4 class="alert-heading">Well done!</h4>-->
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Well, Django comes with it's own logic to handle authentication and authorization flow however you can write your own too. Currently you have raw `SignedUpUsers` model which contain just basic fields, more robust way is to extend Django's built in `User` model for this purpose. If you want more details I can provide some resources to achieve this.

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug pls provide me with the code that will accomplish my task

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug pls answer me

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is full solution. I have done some modifications to your existing solution, I hope this will help you.

Django comes with built in [`User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#user-objects) model which already have authentication logic built in. Great thing is, it can be extended too. So I created `UserDetails` model which extends `User` using `OneToOneField`. Create and put following code in models.py .

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    dob = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

After creating that, create migrations using following command `python manage.py makemigrations` and after that `python manage.py migrate`

**Handling Sign Up logic:**

We already have created our models, now to get data from user We need forms. Django have built in support for handling [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) logic. 
I created two [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) as `UserForm` and `UserDetailsForm`. Here comes a tricky part, both forms are acting as a individual forms and each form is not aware of other. So I created a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/) which is going to be used later to link our `User` with `UserDetails` inside view. Create and put following code in forms.py.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import UserDetails
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
   class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ('email','username','password1', 'password2',)

class UserDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
        fields = ('name', 'dob',)


from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
# Formset is combining UserForm and UserDetailsForm
UserDetailsFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, UserDetails, form=UserDetailsForm, 
extra=1, can_delete = False)
```

To render both forms create a template `signUpTemplate.html`. *(Note: You can style it later)*

**signUpTemplate.html**

```html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {{ user_details_form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now, I have created view as `signUpView` which will handle SignUp requests. Here I passed `UserForm` and `UserDetailsFormSet` in context and rendered the form using template. If you have seen carefully in `signUpTemplate` I am using single form tag `<form>***code***</form>` to render both the forms as it will force to send both the forms in single request.

Now this is how I am processing the forms data in view. First I check for `UserForm`. If UserForm is valid then I process `UserDetailsFormSet` and pass instance of `UserForm` in it (you may have seen `commit=false` parameter in save method. this parameter means that just save it in memory not in actual database). If `UserDetailsFormSet` is valid then I am calling the save() method on both forms. If forms are not valid then it will automatically render the error on template*(this is the power of built in forms)*. Here is the view code in views.py .

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import UserForm, UserDetailsFormSet

def signUpView(request):
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    user_details_form = UserDetailsFormSet(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user_details_form = UserDetailsFormSet(request.POST,instance=user)

            if user_details_form.is_valid():
                user.save()
                user_details_form.save()
                return redirect('login')

    context = {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'user_details_form': user_details_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'signUpTemplate.html',context=context)
```

**Handling Login logic:**

Login functionality is pretty straight forward. To handle login I have created `loginView`. Django provides built in `AuthenticationForm` for handling `User` authentication. To render `AuthenticationForm` create a template `loginTemplate.html`.

**loginTemplate.html**

```html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The `login()` method is Django's built in functionality to handle User Login. Put following code in views.py (Note: do not forget to add URL after successful login in `redirect()` method).

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.conf import settings

def loginView(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('URL_after_successful_login')

    return render(request, 'loginTemplate.html', context = {'form': form})
```

As we have done all the main part, now we can register both views in our apps urls.py file.

**urls.py**

```
from .views import index,loginView,signUpView
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('login', loginView, name = 'login' ),
    path('signup', signUpView, name = 'signup')
]
```

also in your projects urls file do not forget to add referance to your apps url file by putting `path('', include('your_app.urls'))` in urlpatterns (Note: replace your_app with your appname)

Now you can run the server by using `python manage.py runserver` command. Go to your web browser and browse `localhost:port/signup` to get signup page, and `localhost:port/login` to get login page.

I hope you are familiar with [admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/) (i.e [creation of super user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#creating-superusers) and login into admin site), register your model with admin site as follows. And login with your super user credentials and check `User` and `UserDetails` tables at admin site.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import UserDetails

admin.site.register(UserDetails)
```

I hope this will help you. :)