# How to log in to Django with model class User

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am newbie in Django and DRF.

I created object of User class(which is in models.py) and i want with THAT user log in to django. In a nutshell, create django user with model User class. How can i implement it?

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)  #login field in Angular
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)  # name field in Angular
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=254,
    )
```

views.py

```
class UserCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

SerializerClass

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: You shouldn't create your own User class if you want to use Django's inbuilt functionality. Rather than creating your own class you should extend the inbuilt model (only if you need to add more attributes). However, looking at your current model, I don't think you need to even extent it. The inbuilt model already contains those attributes.

Comment: Django have it's own `User` model already built in and it will make your implementation compatible with DRF too. I would suggest to [extend](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) your `User` model with Django's `User`. Reason behind this is DRF natively supports authentication with Djnago `User` so you don't have to write more code, let the library handle it for you. For the login part in DRF, you can refer official docs over [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/).

Comment: For some basic idea about authentication stuff you can read my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61412166/8601641) . However it is implemented using plain Django, but the DRF implementation will be somewhat similar to it, [this](https://sunscrapers.com/blog/django-rest-framework-login-and-authentication/) might help.

Comment: @SwetankPoddar, yes, i've created  User object. And i want to log in. I made post request in Postman and i need to fill username and password in json format. How Django understands what field is username and what password ? Because, i've inserted my username and password and its says 'authentication has failed'

Comment: You *do not* have to create a User model. Django's rest framework doesn't use the modal that you created. Django's inbuilt authentication functionality uses ```from django.contrib.auth.models import User``` this user model. Have a look there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple django auth, very easily explained in the article below
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html

Also, for having a better authentication system, I would suggest you to look for simple JWT tokens:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/12/19/how-to-use-jwt-authentication-with-django-rest-framework.html

Comment: I need to login from ANgular. For example i've already connected them, now , how can retrieve data from ANgular, pass them Django and need to sing up. What is then? Basically, create user without createsuperuser command