# Authenticating using mysql in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new to Django and noob in that concepts. According to my knowledge i am trying to connect the django page to the mysql database. The insertion to the database using form is done correctly, but when i am trying to login with credentials it throws an error. This was very important for my college graduation.

It shows an error called 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'. I need to know whether the data is fetched by that query and how to bind the data.Tq for ur suggestions

```
def login(request):
 email= request.POST['email']
 password=request.POST['password']
 con = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost', database='company')
 cur = con.cursor()
 cur.execute("SELECT email,password from buyerregister where 'email' = '"+email+"' and 'password' = '"+password+"' ")
 data=cur.fetchone()
 con.commit()
 cur.close()
 con.close()
 if data[2] == email and data[3] == password:

     return render(request, "purchase.html")
 else:
     return render(request, "order.html")
```

Comment: if you have stored password in plaintext and using django's authentication system to login, it won't work. as django stores the password after it hashes it.

Comment: besides using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649759/using-prepared-statements-with-mysql-in-python    **prepared statements**, **never save passwordwss** without hashing it in your database

Comment: but it stores the password data in database without any hashing @ruddra

Comment: Django has built in [ORM](https://blog.bitsrc.io/what-is-an-orm-and-why-you-should-use-it-b2b6f75f5e2a) support so you don't have to write queries manually. For setting up your database configs refer [this](https://data-flair.training/blogs/django-database/). After that you can create your authentication system as [follows.](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html)

Comment: But i want to use my own login system. So please help me to overcome this issue, when i am getting this i could easily fetching up the data in my upcoming work pages. Tq @k33da_lets_debug

Comment: First configure your MySQL database as I mentioned earlier. In Django we mostly don't create data tables manually, Django has built in ORM system which is more powerful and it can save you literally hours of writing manual SQL queries(Yes we can write our own queries but it will be in extreme case). So I recommend first learn about Django's [ORM](https://data-flair.training/blogs/django-orm-tutorial/) first. After that see my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61412166/8601641) for building login system. I have mentioned there about handling own login system.

Comment: But in my database i am going to fetch the data from the custom table not from the superusers tables when i do migrate in my project. I would like to fetch the data from the custom table created for my own fields of data. If u dont mind can u send ur mail so i can attach my file so it is easy to analyse @k33da_lets_debug